# Separating "Navigation Title" from "Page Title" on an Internet Site

Tags: 2010, publishing-site, publishing, seo

I am involved in a SEO(Search Engine Optimization) project for a SharePoint 2010 Publishing Site. One optimization that we want to make is to improve the content of our html title elements. Currently, this value comes from the "Title" field of the page's content type. However, the "Title" field is also used by the site's left navigation to display the page name, where we would prefer the shorter name. So, I need a way of separating these two values, what is displayed in the HTML Title element from what is displayed in the navigation.

My first thought is to add a new field to the Page content type named "HTML Title" and use this to store the more descriptive title. Am I overlooking some built-in feature for handling this issue? Has anyone approached this problem differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have done it in the past with the solution that you have in mind. We used following value for `<title>` tag in html.

```
<SharePointWebControls:FieldValue id="PageTitle" FieldName="LongTitle" runat="server"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. If I go with this approach, I might use your field name, "LongTitle"

Answer (score 2):

Is it an option to add a new field on the page content type for example. headline too use it as a title page and then use the title as the title in the navigation?

Comment: Yes, that is certainly an option.